# Builder lifecycle 'creator' failed with status code 51

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-image

In my spring boot application i issue a problem when i 'm trying to build my docker image by this command

```
mvn spring-boot:build-image -DskipTests
```

i see as a result a build failure:

```
  [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------< com.in28minutes.microservices:currency-exchange-service >-------
[INFO] Building currency-exchange-service-docker 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.2:build-image (default-cli) > package @ currency-exchange-service >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0:resources (default-resources) @ currency-exchange-service ---
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ currency-exchange-service ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ currency-exchange-service ---
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\vavil\Desktop\spring-microservices\spring-microservices-v3-main\04.docker\currency-exchange-service\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ currency-exchange-service ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ currency-exchange-service ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.3.0:jar (default-jar) @ currency-exchange-service ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.2:repackage (repackage) @ currency-exchange-service ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.2:build-image (default-cli) < package @ currency-exchange-service <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.2:build-image (default-cli) @ currency-exchange-service ---
[INFO] Building image 'docker.io/in28min/mmv3-currency-exchange-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
[INFO]
[INFO]  > Executing lifecycle version v0.16.0
[INFO]  > Using build cache volume 'pack-cache-3c5bb71319ef.build'
[INFO]
[INFO]  > Running creator
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> ANALYZING
[INFO]     [creator]     Previous image with name "docker.io/in28min/mmv3-currency-exchange-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" not found
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> DETECTING
[INFO]     [creator]     6 of 24 buildpacks participating
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates   3.5.1
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica 9.10.3
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/syft              1.24.2
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/executable-jar    6.6.0
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/dist-zip          5.5.0
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot       5.22.1
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> RESTORING
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> BUILDING
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for CA Certificates 3.5.1
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Helper: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Creating /layers/paketo-buildpacks_ca-certificates/helper/exec.d/ca-certificates-helper
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for BellSoft Liberica 9.10.3
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica
[INFO]     [creator]       Build Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_JLINK_ARGS           --no-man-pages --no-header-files --strip-debug --compress=1  configure custom link arguments (--output must be omitted)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_JLINK_ENABLED        false                                                        enables running jlink tool to generate custom JRE
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_TYPE                 JRE                                                          the JVM type - JDK or JRE
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_VERSION              11                                                           the Java version
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_ENABLED           false                                                        enables Java remote debugging support
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_PORT              8000                                                         configure the remote debugging port
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_SUSPEND           false                                                        configure whether to suspend execution until a debugger has attached
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_HEAP_DUMP_PATH                                                                       write heap dumps on error to this path
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JAVA_NMT_ENABLED        true                                                         enables Java Native Memory Tracking (NMT)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JAVA_NMT_LEVEL          summary                                                      configure level of NMT, summary or detail
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JFR_ARGS                                                                             configure custom Java Flight Recording (JFR) arguments
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JFR_ENABLED             false                                                        enables Java Flight Recording (JFR)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JMX_ENABLED             false                                                        enables Java Management Extensions (JMX)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JMX_PORT                5000                                                         configure the JMX port
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_HEAD_ROOM           0                                                            the headroom in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_LOADED_CLASS_COUNT  35% of classes                                               the number of loaded classes in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_THREAD_COUNT        250                                                          the number of threads in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS                                                                        the JVM launch flags
[INFO]     [creator]         Using Java version 18 extracted from MANIFEST.MF
[INFO]     [creator]       No valid JRE available, providing matching JDK instead. Using a JDK at runtime has security implications.
[INFO]     [creator]        : Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]       Warning: Dependency has no SHA256. Skipping cache.
[INFO]     [creator]         Downloading from
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to invoke layer creator
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to get dependency
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to download
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to request
[INFO]     [creator]     Get "": unsupported protocol scheme ""
[INFO]     [creator]     ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  13.631 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-03-02T10:31:09+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.2:build-image (default-cli) on project currency-exchange-service: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3
.0.2:build-image failed: Builder lifecycle 'creator' failed with status code 51 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

I tried to change my pom.xml and also some versions to check if there is version compatibility problem but i still facing the same issue.

Here is my **pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.in28minutes.microservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>currency-exchange-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>currency-exchange-service-docker</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!--        <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
                </dependency>
         -->
        <!-- Spring Boot 3+ Tracing -->

        <!-- Micrometer > Brave/OpenTelemetry > Zipkin -->

        <!-- Micrometer - Vendor-neutral application observability facade. Instrument your JVM-based application code without vendor lock-in.  Observation (Metrics & Logs) + Tracing.-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-observation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Brave as Bridge -->

        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.reporter2</groupId
            <artifactId>zipkin-reporter-brave</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->

        <!-- Open Telemetry as Bridge -->
        <!-- Open Telemetry - Simplified Observability (metrics, logs, and traces) -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-zipkin</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <name>in28min/mmv3-${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</name>
                    </image>
                    <pullPolicy>IF_NOT_PRESENT</pullPolicy>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

I also tried to change this version:

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
```

to:

```
  <version>2.7.4</version>
```

but i m getting error in some classes because i use imports such as:

```
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
```

Comment: Please show the full output of the build, especially the output from the image builder (lines that start with `[INFO]     [creator]`).

Comment: @ScottFrederick I added the full output in my post

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your image build is failing when trying to download a JRE or JDK to use in the resulting image. The output shows `Using Java version 18 extracted from MANIFEST.MF`, but the Paketo Buildpack for BellSoft Liberica shown in the output (`paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica 9.10.3`) does not support Java 18 (see [release notes](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica/releases/tag/v9.10.3) for the versions it does support).

The `Using Java version 18 extracted from MANIFEST.MF` output indicates that the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file in the jar file generated by Spring Boot contains the line `Build-Jdk-Spec: 18`. This should not be the case since your `pom.xml` above has `<java.version>17</java.version>`, so something does not look right there.

You should make sure that the `Build-Jdk-Spec` entry in the jar manifest matches one of the JRE entries supported by the Paketo Buildpack for Bellsoft Liberica (that is, `17` or `19`). Maven should set this  automatically unless something else in the build is modifying the jar manifest.

You also have the option of explicitly configuring the buildpack to use the JRE version you want, as shown in the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.examples.builder-configuration).

**Example:**
POM.xml with Java 17:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    ...
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        ...
    </properties>
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Make sure `mvn spring-boot:build-image` uses the Java version defined in this project -->
                    <image>
                        <env>
                            <BP_JVM_VERSION>${java.version}</BP_JVM_VERSION>
                        </env>
                    </image>
                    ...
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            ...
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: @Pascal The configuration like you added in the example is not necessary. The `java.version` property from the build will be copied to the `Build-Jdk-Spec` attribute in `MANIFEST.MF`, and Paketo buildpacks will automatically use that to decide what Java version to install. You'd only need to set the `BP_JVM_VERSION` if you want buildpacks to use something other than what's been set in `java.version`.

Comment: I am not that knowledgeable regarding that matter, but, in my maven project, `java.version` is 17 , but still `Build-Jdk-Spec: 18` was present in the generated jar! In IntelliJ, module java language setting was 17. The thing is that, also in IntelliJ, the project java language level was 18! a bad discrepancy. So, I prefer the "explicit way" I am suggesting in the example: it works no matter what are the IntelliJ settings. This way, the java language level IS for sure the one defined in maven project, which is really what I (we all?) want. What is your view on that?

Answer (score 6):

Solved my issue, I have java-19 installed in system but app running was on java 17. So adding below line into pom XML solved my problem and created image. <BP_JVM_VERSION>${java.version}</BP_JVM_VERSION>

Comment: I had the same issue with JDK 19 installed locally. Adding this line solved it for me as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After long time struggle found this discussion and fixed my issue. Thanks for the tips.

I'm using Java 21 and eclipse showing the compiler version is 20 in the project build path.

So i have updated the below in my pom.xml and worked fine.

```
<java.version>20</java.version>
```

And

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <image>
            <name>DOCKER_USERNAME/${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</name>
            <env>
                <BP_JVM_VERSION>${java.version}</BP_JVM_VERSION>
            </env>
        </image>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```