# Spring boot & Docker : Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.0:build-image

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-image

I am learning spring-boot and docker so I am new to this.
I try to build a docker image using this command : ./mvnw spring-boot:build-image but it fails a the Running creator step.
Docker desktop is running on Windows 11.
I tried SDK 17 and 21 with same result. I did not found an answer on the internet that helped. Below is my pom.xml.

Thanks for any help

```
 > Running creator
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> ANALYZING
[INFO]     [creator]     Image with name "docker.io/library/docker-demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" not found
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> DETECTING
[INFO]     [creator]     6 of 26 buildpacks participating
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates   3.6.6
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica 10.4.4
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/syft              1.41.1
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/executable-jar    6.8.3
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/dist-zip          5.6.8
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot       5.27.7
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> RESTORING
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> BUILDING
[INFO]     [creator]
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for CA Certificates 3.6.6
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Helper: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Creating /layers/paketo-buildpacks_ca-certificates/helper/exec.d/ca-certificates-helper
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for BellSoft Liberica 10.4.4
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica
[INFO]     [creator]       Build Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_JLINK_ARGS           --no-man-pages --no-header-files --strip-debug --compress=1  configure custom link arguments (--output must be omitted)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_JLINK_ENABLED        false                                                        enables running jlink tool to generate custom JRE
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_TYPE                 JRE                                                          the JVM type - JDK or JRE
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_VERSION              17                                                           the Java version
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_ENABLED           false                                                        enables Java remote debugging support
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_PORT              8000                                                         configure the remote debugging port
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_SUSPEND           false                                                        configure whether to suspend execution until a debugger has attached
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_HEAP_DUMP_PATH                                                                       write heap dumps on error to this path
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JAVA_NMT_ENABLED        true                                                         enables Java Native Memory Tracking (NMT)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JAVA_NMT_LEVEL          summary                                                      configure level of NMT, summary or detail
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JFR_ARGS                                                                             configure custom Java Flight Recording (JFR) arguments
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JFR_ENABLED             false                                                        enables Java Flight Recording (JFR)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JMX_ENABLED             false                                                        enables Java Management Extensions (JMX)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JMX_PORT                5000                                                         configure the JMX port
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_HEAD_ROOM           0                                                            the headroom in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_LOADED_CLASS_COUNT  35% of classes                                               the number of loaded classes in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_THREAD_COUNT        250                                                          the number of threads in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS                                                                        the JVM launch flags
[INFO]     [creator]         Using Java version 20 extracted from MANIFEST.MF
[INFO]     [creator]       No valid JRE available, providing matching JDK instead. Using a JDK at runtime has security implications.
[INFO]     [creator]        : Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]       Warning: Dependency has no SHA256. Skipping cache.
[INFO]     [creator]         Downloading from 
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to invoke layer creator
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to get dependency
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to download
[INFO]     [creator]     ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to request
[INFO]     [creator]     Get "": unsupported protocol scheme ""
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  14.179 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-12-22T08:13:29+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.0:build-image (default-cli) on project docker-demo: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.0:build-image failed: Builder lifecycle 'creator' failed with status code 51 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>fr.wcs</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>docker-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're facing the same problem as this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75602761/builder-lifecycle-creator-failed-with-status-code-51)

In your build logs, you can see that it tries to load JDK 20

```
Using Java version 20 extracted from MANIFEST.MF
```

You can define the good java-version using [this documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.examples.builder-configuration)
It should looks like the following :

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <image>
            <env>
                <BP_JVM_VERSION>17</BP_JVM_VERSION> <!-- or use your ${java.version} property -->
            </env>
        </image>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```